# How to add localisation to permission dialog in an Ionic/Cordova app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm adding a permission string to ask for user consent but I would like the string to reflect the device language.

How can I add localisation to the `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` option in an ionic/cordova app?

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSUserTrackingUsageDescription">
        <string>Dies hilft uns dir weiterhin personalisierte Angebote anzuzeigen.</string>
    </config-file>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems quite pointless because the permission request uses an Android native dialog that will use the **device's current language** always.

If you want an earlier dialog before the real one, simply add it in the current app's language.

Comment: this is related to iOS